# make sure that only one bot instance is running error

Tags: python, telebot

I deployed telegramm bot on a VPS server. After a while (i think a few hours) it gives error

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

But it was bot with token which i never used anywhere else before.(I created new bot right befor the deploy) And while it was running on server i didn't run it on my local machine. How it can be? What i can try to do?

I dont think bot code is matter in this case, but better to say that it's just about sending and handling text messages and photos.

````
import telebot
import os.path
from telebot import types
import gspread
from random import choice

def change_user_stage(call, value):
    if isinstance(call, types.Message):
        USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(call.chat.id), in_column=3).row
        worksheet.update_acell('B{}'.format(USER_ROW), value)

    elif isinstance(call, types.CallbackQuery):
        USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(call.message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
        worksheet.update_acell('B{}'.format(USER_ROW), value)

    else:
        print(0)

#func for fitback to false answer
negatives = ['не совсем', 'почти', 'неа', 'немного не так', 'близко', 'попробуй еще', 'немного не то', 'немного ошибся', 'неправильно']

def negative(call):
    if isinstance(call, types.Message):
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, choice(negatives))

    elif isinstance(call, types.CallbackQuery):
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, choice(negatives))


bot = telebot.TeleBot(******)

#get into google service account by credentials
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='credentials.json')
#find required sheet on our service account
sh = gc.open_by_key(******) #our sheet key from url
#get info from worksheet
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

#hold photo open
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PHOTO1 = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'TheTower.jpeg')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Ты запустил наш квест - значит определенно принял верное решение "
                                      "ведь по прохождению квеста ты побольше узнаешь о столице солнечного Башкортостана и получишь нашу сувенирную продукцию, "
                                      " а также приятные подарки от наших партнеров ( а они у нас, кстати, очень крутые!)\n\n"
                                      "Перед началом ответь пожалуйста на несколько вопросов. Это очень важно для нас!\n"
                                      "Тем самым ты даешь согласие на обработку своих персональных данных (все данные останутся строго конфиденциальными)")

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши свое ФИО')

    if worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3) is None:
        #add user id to worksheet in correct place
        TOTAL_USERS = int(worksheet.get('A2')[0][0])
        worksheet.update_acell('C{}'.format(2 + TOTAL_USERS), message.chat.id)
        worksheet.update_acell('A2', TOTAL_USERS + 1)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, second_question)

def second_question(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сколько тебе лет?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, third_question)
    USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
    #updating google sheet q1
    worksheet.update_acell('D{}'.format(USER_ROW), message.from_user.username)
    worksheet.update_acell('E{}'.format(USER_ROW), message.from_user.first_name)
    worksheet.update_acell('F{}'.format(USER_ROW), message.text)

def third_question(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажи свою почту (никаких рассылок и спама!)")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, after_question)
    #updating google shell q2
    USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
    worksheet.update_acell('G{}'.format(USER_ROW), message.text)

def after_question(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='В путь', callback_data='start')
    markup.add(button)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо!\nА теперь давай начнем квест!', reply_markup=markup)
    #updating google shell q3
    USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
    worksheet.update_acell('H{}'.format(USER_ROW), message.text)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "start")
def start(call):
     bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

     bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "-Ну что, где встречаемся?\n -<b>На ГД!</b>\n\n"
                                            "Наверное, ты поражен нашей оригинальностью, но место встречи изменить нельзя!", parse_mode='html' )
     bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ты знал, что Гостиный двор хранит в себе страшные тайны??\n\n"
                                            "В торговых рядах в 90-х видели призрака старого купца \n\n"
                                            "Один из рабочих рассказал, что странная фигура замахивалась кнутом на людей."
                                            "Позже призрака увидел и охранник вовремя ночного обхода. Старый купец поднимался по лестнице, но исчез, как только его стали искать!\n\n "
                                            "Мы думаем, что именно по этой причине Гостинка закрывается до наступления темноты...\n"
                                            "Будьте осторожны!\n\n"
                                            "Предлагаем попробовать запечатлеть призрака на фотографии\n "
                                            "Кидай сюда свой результат и получай координаты следующей точки!")

     #updating user stage
     change_user_stage(call, 1)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'IAmHere')
def tasks(call):
   bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

   bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Прогуляйся по саду, посиди в беседке, пройдись по висячему мосту"
                                          " и внимательно осмотрись по сторонам \n\n"
                                          "Чтобы получить следующую точку, напиши нам количество оленей в парке (неживых!!) ")


   #updating user stage
   change_user_stage(call, 2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'Habirov')
def history_check(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Проверим твои знания об истории Уфы, чтобы получить следующую точку?\n\n'
                                           'Напиши, в каком году было построено здание Администрации Главы РБ')



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'NearTheTower')
def tower(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    photo = open(PHOTO1, 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, photo)
    photo.close()
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Фух, наконец-то ты тут!\n\n'
                                           'В прошлом это была водонапорная башня, которая в 1957 превратилась в обсерваторию для студентов БашГУ.\n\n'
                                           'Сейчас же башня является объектом культурного наследия и локальным местом Уфимской молодежи,'
                                           ' откуда открывается красивый вид на закаты у реки Белой\n\n'
                                           'Чтобы получить следующую точку, попробуй воспроизвести старую фотографию башни и отправь ее нам!⬇️')

    #updating user stage
    change_user_stage(call, '4')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'CatMeeted')
def cat_name(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Раз ты уже пришел в гости к коту, то пора познакомиться и узнать, как его зовут.\n'
                                      'Это и будет твоим ключом к получению следующей точки!')

    #updating user stage
    change_user_stage(call, 6)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'IAmIn')
def cypher(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мне нужна подсказка', callback_data='NeedHelp')
    markup.add(button)

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ой, ты уже почти прошел весь маршрут\n'
                                      'Так держать!\n\n '
                                      'Чтобы получить следующую локацию, попробуй узнать, как переводится слово Заман. '
                                      'Для этого необходимо разгадать небольшой шифр: \n\n'
                                      '<B>31-17-16-23-1</b>\n\n'
                                      'Если разгадал, то скорее пиши ответ!', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

    #updating user stage
    change_user_stage(call, 7)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'NeedHelp')
def need_help(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Данный шифр называется A1Z26')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'IAmHere2')
def black_squares(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Что такое квадратики?', callback_data='WhatIsSquares')
    markup.add(button)

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Авторами панно, создаваемого в 1973 году, являются Александр Пантелеев и Александр Юдин.'
                                           ' На композиции изображено солнце, радуга и счастливые люди в белых халатах☀️\n\n'
                                           'Мрамор и яшму для мозаики добывали на Урале,'
                                           ' а вот пластинки из непрозрачного стекла привезли из Москвы.\n\n'
                                           'Чтобы отправиться дальше, напиши, сколько черных квадратиков изображено на панно?◾️', reply_markup=markup)
    change_user_stage(call, 8)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'WhatIsSquares')
def squares_explanetion(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Обрати внимание на пол, на котором стоят люди, изображенные на мозаике!')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'LastPoint')
def last_point(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Поздравляем, ты прошел весь квест и узнал Уфу чуточку лучше! \n\n'
                                           'Спасибо, что провел это время с нами! '
                                           'Наша команда очень старалась Поэтому мы надеемся, что тебе понравилось,'
                                           ' и ты открыл для себя новые классные места!\n\n'
                                           'Чтобы получить сувенирную продукцию и купоны от наших партнеров,'
                                           ' покажи баристе пройденный квест и скажи кодовое слово «Айда по Уфе»\n\n'
                                           'Мы будем безумно благодарны, если ты расскажешь о нас своим друзьям и оставишь обратную связь,'
                                           ' ведь это сильно поможет нам развиваться дальше!\n\n'
                                           'Ссылочка на обратную связь ⬇️'
                                           'До новых встреч!')


#------------------------------------------handle photos and check it for STAGE----------------------------------------
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo_answering(message):
    #chek user's stage
    USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
    USER_STAGE = worksheet.cell(USER_ROW, 2).value

    if USER_STAGE == '1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я тут', callback_data='IAmHere')
        markup.add(button)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Крутая фотка!"
                                          "Уверены, призраки тебя больше не потревожат\n\n"
                                          "Отправляйся в сад им. Салавата Юлаева через Софьюшкину аллею.\n\n"
                                          "Кстати, интересный факт!\n\n"
                                          "Изначально аллея была названа Софийским или Театральным садом."
                                          " Только после смерти Софьи Александровны (жены Г.С. Аксакова) жители города переименовали ее в Софьюшкину."
                                          " Единственную в Уфе аллею классического типа\n\n "
                                          "Если ты уже дошел до сада, то скорее жми на кнопку⬇️", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

    elif USER_STAGE == '4':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вау! А ты мастер фотографий!'
                                          'Теперь получай следующую локацию⬇️\n\n'
                                          '«У лукоморья дуб зелёный; Златая цепь на дубе том: И днём и ночью кот учёный Всё ходит по цепи кругом»\n\n'
                                          'Знакомое стихотворение?\n'
                                          'Вспомни фамилию автора этого произведения и отправляйся на улицу, названную в его честь!\n\n'
                                          'Поговаривают, что там находится загадочный сквер с русалкой на ветвях'
                                          'Найди ее и пришли нам доказательства!\n\n'
                                          'P.S. - ищи сквер в перекрёстке между улицами Гафури и Аксакова')

        change_user_stage(message, 5)

    elif USER_STAGE == '5':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я встретился с котом', callback_data='CatMeeted')
        markup.add(button)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Русалку нашел, погнали дальше!\n\n'
                                          'Предлагаем тебе зайти в гости к коту и присмотреть для себя классные вещички\n\n'
                                          'Отправляйся в секонд-хенд «Кот и Шмот» на ул. Коммунистическую 45/3\n\n'
                                          'Для наших участников действует скидка -35% на любую вещь '
                                          'Просто покажи на экране прохождение квеста и скажи кодовое слово «Айда по Уфе»!\n\n'
                                          'Кстати, по пути мы советуем заглянуть в музей им. Нестерова и погрузиться с головой в искусство.\n '
                                          'Но не забудь свериться с графиком их работы!', reply_markup=markup)
        change_user_stage(message, 5.5)

    else:
        print('фото на некоректной стадии')


#-----------------------------handle every text messsage and check it for stage or question answer--------------------------------
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_answering(message):
    #get user stage
    USER_ROW = worksheet.find(str(message.chat.id), in_column=3).row
    USER_STAGE = worksheet.cell(USER_ROW, 2).value

    if USER_STAGE == '2':
        if message.text == '2':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Дошел до дома, встретил Хабирова!', callback_data='Habirov')
            markup.add(button)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А ты хорош в математике\n\n'
                                              'Пора осмотреть красоты нашего города на обзорной площадке перед Домом республики\n\n'
                                              'Отправляйся на ул. Тукаева 46!  ',
                                              reply_markup=markup)

            change_user_stage(message, 3)
        else:
            negative(message)

    elif USER_STAGE == '7':
        if message.text.lower() == 'эпоха':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ZAMAN = Эпоха\n\n'
                                              '«Настала эпоха, которая может переломить утрату памяти, собственной истории и забвения.'
                                              ' ZAMAN возрождает интерес людей к самим себе,'
                                              ' к своей истории и побуждает задуматься, что будет завтра»')

            change_user_stage(message, 7.5)

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я тут!', callback_data='IAmHere2')
            markup.add(button)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну что, отправляемся дальше?\n\n'
                                              'В свое время Советскому Союзу ещё было что сказать и миру, и собственным гражданам.'
                                              ' Поэтому на домах города расположились интересные разноцветные мозаики\n\n'
                                              'Приглашаем тебя взглянуть на одну из тех, что находится в самом центре города!\n\n '
                                              'Отправляйся на ул. Кирова 15 к Академии наук! ', reply_markup=markup)

        else:
            negative(message)

    elif  USER_STAGE == '6':
        if message.text.lower() == 'ламба':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я погрузился в искусство', callback_data='IAmIn')
            markup.add(button)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                             'Предлагаем ознакомиться с современным искусством, расположенным в музее ZAMAN на ул. Мустая Карима 6.\n\n'
                             '«ZAMAN переосмысляет и преобразует локальную культуру, делая ее живой и своевременной.\n\n'
                             'На втором этаже здания находится классный книжный магазин, где ты можешь найти не только книги,'
                             ' но и открытки с Уфой, а также стикеры от башкирских художников', reply_markup=markup)

            change_user_stage(message, 6.5)

        else:
            negative(message)

    elif USER_STAGE == '3':
        if message.text == '1979':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я дошел до башни!', callback_data='NearTheTower')
            markup.add(button)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Молодец!\n\n'
                                              'Отправляем тебя на заброшку '
                                              '(не переживай, все в рамках закона!)\n\n'
                                              'Иди на ул. Алтайская 4 и ориентируйся на кирпичную башню вдалеке. ', reply_markup=markup)

            change_user_stage(message, 3.5)

        else:
            negative(message)

    elif USER_STAGE == '8':
        if message.text == '15':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ура! Я дошел до последней точки!', callback_data='LastPoint')
            markup.add(button)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фух, ты наконец на финишной прямой! \n\n'
                                              'Беги в кофейню Union на ул. Ленина 44/46 и забирай свои заслуженные подарки!'
                                              , reply_markup=markup)

            change_user_stage(message, 8.5)

        else:
            negative(message)

    else:
        print('некоректный текст:'+ message.text)


bot.polling()```
````

Tried to change bot token